# How to show a Post based on attending an Event in general, and based on the date a user is attending an Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say theres a music festival called Musiczilla from Jan 1st to Jan 31st.

A User can attend the event and specify the dates they will be there

A Post can be about the Event in general, or about the time the Post User will be there in specific.

- user1 is attending the event from Jan 1 to Jan 7
- user2 is attending the event from Jan 5 to Jan 13
- user3 is attending the event from Jan 8 to Jan 15

So.

- If user1 posts a general event Post like "Dont forget to bring your ticket", then all users attending the event should see it.
- If user1 posts a specific event Post like "Who wants to grab a beer at Musiczilla?". Only people who will be there on one or more days that user1 is there should see it (in this case only user1 and user2, but not user3).
- Likewise if user2 posts "Who want to grab a beer?", then user1, user2, and user3 should see it.

What is the best way to handle this in my model and controller?

Comment: Can a user attend on broken date-ranges, e.g. Jan. 1-3 and 10?

Comment: Yes, but I would probably structure is as two separate event records for the User.

Comment: This sounds fairly arbitrary. What classifies a post as "general" or "specific"? That the post is "targeted" for a specific day?

Comment: The Post author would select if a post was a general event post or specific to their time at the event, currently I have a table row for event_general:boolean.

Comment: How are you storing the attendance dates?

Comment: User has_many Events which has_many Posts. Event has start_date and end_date(for the user). I dont want to create an Event for Musiczilla (Jan1 to Jan31), because I want to open it up to cities too. i.e. User is in Manhattan for a week and will see all general Manhattan posts and Posts from users in Manhattan at the same time, but not posts from users in Manhattan at other times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick attempt:

```
class Post
  attr_accessible :general
  belongs_to :event, :user

  def self.visible_to_user(viewing_user)
    joins(:user).
    where(general: true).
    where(
      "(general = false AND (users.start_date <= ?) AND (users.end_date >= ?)) OR general = true", 
      viewing_user.end_date, 
      viewing_user.start_date
    )
  end
end

class User
  attr_accessible :start_date, :end_date
end

class Event
  attr_accessible :start_date, :end_date
end
```

Query's a bit ugly though.